# Word for emotionally intense situation?

Tags: single-word-requests

This may be a somewhat archaic word, but I recall learning it from *Nabokov's Lolita*. It has that 'vortex','spasm' sort of phonetic similarity lying on the tip of my tongue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maelstrom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maelstrom) :

> - situation in which there are a lot of confused activities, emotions, etc.

(M-W)

Comment: Closest, it was actually paroxysm! 

*It was a formal word, I forgot to mention this

Comment: @silenceislife chasly's suggestion is actually a better fit for your question; it references the situation rather than the outburst.

Answer (score 0):

*[Tailspin](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tailspin)* may suggest it:

> - (Informal) A loss of emotional control sometimes resulting in emotional collapse.

The Free Dictionary